# KineticJS Animate shape to go to exact position

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have a polygon and I am animating it to go in a linear path.

```
var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
shape.setX(99);
if(shape.getPosition().y < window.innerHeight/2){shape.setY(shape.getPosition().y + frame.time/48);};
  }, layer);
```

So this animation works except the shape never goes to the center of the page's height, instead it is always a bit after. I know this is because of `shape.getPosition().y < window.innerHeight/2` but making it `shape.getPosition().y == window.innerHeight/2` will cause the shape to never stop because the calculation will never be exactly `window.innerHeight/2` I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how I could animate an object to an exact coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use Tween?

```
var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
  node : rect,
  y : window.innerHeight / 2,
  duration : 0.5
});
tween.play();
```

http://jsbin.com/zihoqe/1/edit?js,output